# Bootstrap Popover doesn't work with MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to use `"popover"` with a  `"@Html.PasswordFor"` MVC helper element, but displays only the title and not the content.
The code is:

```
 @Html.PasswordFor(model => model.Password, new {rel = "popover", 
                   data_original_title = "Choose new password",  
                   data_content = "minimum 8 chars"})
```

It generates HTML code like this:

```
<input rel="popover" data-original-title="Choose new password" 
       data-content="minimum 8 chars" id="Password" name="Password"
       type="password" 
/>
```

**Javascript Code**:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#Password").popover({ trigger: 'hover' });   
});
```

That code works, but only displays the title ("Choose new password") and not displays the content ("minimum 8 chars")

I tried writing the HTML code directly and it works fine, and it is the same code!!! but with Razor syntax not works.

Can anyone help me? 
I add an image with the result

[image: Result]

Comment: If you used the HTML directly and it works but it is not working with Razor, then Razor **must** not be generating the HTML you think it is. Please inspect the source of the HTML page and compare the generated mark-up with the copy you know works. In the difference lies your problem.

Comment: Razor generates exactly the same code, in fact I copied the code generated by Razor, to test.
The used HTML code is the code generated by Razor (and works fine)

Comment: Not that I don't believe you, but it just seems *unlikely*. If you what you say is true, it would mean either a) your browser has some way of knowing what technology is serving the markup (it doesn't) and is choosing to act differently or b) your browser is intermittently behaving differently when presented the same markup (unlikely). The more probable cause is the markup is slightly different. I don't have time to experiment with this myself right now, but if there is still no solution, I'll try it out myself tonight.

Comment: I tested this out myself and it all worked as expected. I made sure that I was using the latest jQuery (1.8.3) and the latest bootstrap (2.2.2) and made sure that JS block was present on my page. The only other suggestion I have for you is to use Firebug to ensure all your resource files (JS and CSS) are present and look for CSS glitches or JS errors. Other than that, the code you posted works properly; your problem must be outside the context of what you have included in your question. Good luck!

Comment: Have you checked what the data-content value is at the time that you bind the popover? Something like alert($('#Password').data('content'));  Just to make sure that the MVC unobtrusive stuff isn't overwriting this value.

Comment: The problem was a CSS class ("input-prepend")
I have a "Input" control inside a DIV with that class.
That class in "bootstrap.css" "defines font-size:0;" so I couldn't see the text, although the title could see properly. Thanks Jesse Webb and Miika L

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was a CSS class ("input-prepend")
I have a "Input" control inside a DIV with that class.
That class in "bootstrap.css" "defines font-size:0;" so I couldn't see the text, although the title could see properly. Thanks Jesse Webb and Miika L